# Control a SWF file using backend programing?

Tags: php, python, actionscript-3, flash

I have been search for a few days now for a way to work on this.

Basically I could like to send flashvars to my swf file using some backend language like PHP or Python, then execute it and capture the output.

I looked up to [Ming](http://libming.org) but it seems that this is only a lib for create SWF file, not much on manipulate already created file.

Thank you!

Comment: What does it mean to "manipulate" an already created SWF file to you? What do you want to do that defines "manipulating" it?

Comment: Let me explain further: I have a SWF file and a PHP/Python script. From this PHP script, I could like to call the SWF File with flash variable and do the SWF job. This is what i meant

Comment: Basically, something like interop between Flash and some backend language

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it 'on load basis', you can simply provide flash vars (for example put some flashvars depending on situation and embed the swf into html).

But if you need to have almost real time control over the flash, you have a few options:

- socket connections - very hard (not to say impossible) to implement with php, and a kind of complex job
- make the swf make a call to php, and get some information; then execute what you need depending on that information

I would advise you to use the second option - chose the action depending on situation, and let the swf client get it itself (either save it in file, db or calculate it realtime - it's up to you; the important is that you don't pass it to client, client makes query to get it).

Comment: Yes it's only per job basis, however is there a way to execute swf file from Serverside with flashvars? Because the client side is web base and run on machines that don't have flash install. There are functions obfuscated in SWF that I can't port to PHP.

Comment: Wait, you say that the client doesn't have flash player installed?! What do you mean by 'execute'? The client should simply open a web page :)